# The mean and standard deviation of an Kernel Density Estimation

Tags: standard-deviation, mean, python, kernel-smoothing, kde

[I have crossed posted this from StackOverflow. Not sure if this is allowed, but maybe there is a Python answer, or maybe there is a good stats answer]

I have fitted a `Kernel Density Estimation` using `statsmodels` to some data with a code snippet like this. Basically just using the example code from the website. I import statsmodels, set the observations to X and fit a KDE using the KDEUnivatiate.fit method.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
X = observations['All']
kde = sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(X)
kde.fit()
```

Cool, when I plot the `KDE`, `CDF` and `Hazard function` i get a very nice view combined with my histogram and immediately i saw something interesting and now I  want to figure out the `mean` and `standard deviation` of the KDE I obtained.

How to I do this?

regards
tobie

Comment: Do you mean the standard deviation of the estimate itself, or the mean and the standard deviation of the resulting distribution? I don't see how the latter would be preferred over the mean and standard deviation of the original data. And cross-posting is frowned upon, and may cause the question to be closed. At the very least, you should have posted the specific URL of your SO question.

Comment: Can't you integrate? You got PDF, means and std are simple integrals.